# How to get this image control from TabItem.Header?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabitem

I'm trying to access an image from a `DockPanel` inside a `TabItem.Header` to set it's `Visibility` (however I can't use MVVM approach in this case and binding concept). I would like to update its property in C# Code.

How can I do this?

**C# Code :**

```
public T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

```
// Method Call
var TaskTabItem = new TabItem();
TaskTabItem = MainWindow.SelectedItem as TabItem;
var dockpanel = GetVisualChild<DockPanel>((DockPanel)TaskTabItem.Header);
Image img = (Image) dockpanel.Children[0];
img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

**Xaml Code:**

```
<TabItem x:Name="MyTab" >
    <TabItem.Header>
        <DockPanel x:Name="TabHeaderPanel">
            <Image x:Name="TabIcon" Source="../icons/icon1.png" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Home Page"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: In which context do you want to change the visiblity of the header image? Should it only be displayed if the tab is selected and disappear otherwise?

Comment: Trying to find a visual child of type DockPanel in a parent element that is already a DockPanel makes no sense at all. Write `var dockpanel = (DockPanel)TaskTabItem.Header;`

Comment: @thatguy , when the user click on a button validate in the selectedtabItem

Comment: @JuniorDev13 Validate? What do you by that?

Comment: @Clemens , the line that you wrote causes this exception `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel'.`

Comment: @thatguy Validate Input form , why do you ask about this ? I don't think is it important to know, I'm asking and searching for a solution for getting a Image control inside TabItem.Header , I can't find any relation between your question and my problem?

Comment: @JuniorDev13 That is your code...

Comment: @Clemens , what do you mean ? As you know I'm trying to find a solution to get this image , could you help me to get this working?

Comment: @JuniorDev13 I do not understand what clicking a button and validaton has to do with your question. What I need to know is: Do you want to make the image visible only for the currently selected tab, so it is collapsed again when the selection changes or is selection completely unrelated and you just want to make this image visible by a button click or anything else?

Comment: What I mean is that there is already `(DockPanel)TaskTabItem.Header` in the code you are showing. That will obviously only work for the TabeItem of which you have shown the XAML, not any other possible TabItem that may be selected.

Comment: @thatguy I'm just want to make this image visible by a button click , that what I would like to do

Comment: @Clemens, Yes I know this and I will added later a condition for this tabItem when it's selected , the dockpanel exists only on this tabItem not in the other tabItems